# Unable to editing user profiles

Tags: user-profile, email, alert

I've SharePoint Server 2007 installed on Windows Server 2003 (x32). I'm trying to create `Alerts` but I get the error:

> The following users do not have e-mail
>   addresses specified: System Account, 
>   pc-Name\user1, pc-Name\user2. Alerts
>   have been created successfully but
>   these  users will not receive e-mail
>   notifications until valid e-mail
>   addresses have  been provided

I am not able to even edit user profile information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. Actually I've enabled shared services provider on server so I'm not able to edit the profiles from **`People and Groups`** page from Site Collection pages. You need to go to **`Shared Services Provider`** site and from there to **`People and Groups`** to edit user profile.